# Write the method that takes four integer arguments and returns true if and only if at least three of the four values are the same

Tags: boolean, conditional-statements

Write the method public static boolean atLeastThreeMatch(int a, 
int b, int c, int d) that takes four integer arguments and returns true if and only if at least three of the four values are the same. For example, if the values passed in are 5, 3, 5, 5, it would return 
true. If the values passed in are 7, 3, 7, 9, it would return false.

To complete the task I wrote every possible condition that would satisfy the desired output. I didn't like doing it that way and I feel there is an easier way to acquire the desired output. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Answer (score 0):

cehck below code snippet in which Set is preserving all input values. Set contains only distinct values so if set contains less/equal to 2 values that means atleast three values are equal.

```
public boolean atLeastThreeMatch(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d);
    Set<Integer> counter = new HashSet<Integer>();
    counter.addAll(values);
    if(counter.size() <=2){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a counter that counts the equalities between numbers. For example:

```
int counter=0;
if(num1 == num2)
    counter++;
```

At last:

```
return counter==3;
```